# Why does the focus point distances of an ellipse sum up to the length of the major axis diameter

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Why does the distances from the focus points of an ellipse to arbitrary point in the ellipse sum up to the length of the diameter of the ellipse in the major axis? In other words, how to prove:

[image]

I have seen videos and papers, where this is proved by using the picture on the left. But does this hold in every case no matter where the blue dot $(x,y)$ is on the ellipse?

Question: How to prove that $d_1+d_2 = \hat{d}_1+\hat{d}_2= 2a$ always?

Thnx for any help =)

Comment: The *sum of distance = constant* is THE definition of an ellipse. What is the definition of ellipse you are using?

Comment: This one :) http://nebula.deanza.edu/~bloom/math43/ellipse-derivation.pdf

Comment: aah...okay, so it's definition...not a fact?

Comment: As stated, your question is true by definition. More meaningful question you can ask is given such a definition. how to reduce the equation of an ellipse to its standard form (define the one you want). Alternatively, given the equation of an ellipse in its standard form or some form of conics satisfies some conditon, how to verify it satisfy this definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to characterize an ellipse is by stating that this is the set of all points which have *equal sum of distances* to the pair of foci. So if one uses this as the definition, then if $d_1+d_2=2a$ holds in the left picture, then it must hold for all $\hat d_1+\hat d_2$.

If you use a different definition of an ellipse, you might have to prove the constant distance sum up front, but this depends very much on which definition you use instead. The way I understand the OP, this is not the case here.